# Google App Engine: PHP Code in Subdirectories not Executing

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have the following code on Google App Engine:

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$database = "db-name";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = new mysqli(null, 
    $username, 
    $password, 
    $database,
    null,
    '/cloudsql/project-name:cloud-sql'
    );

if($dbhandle->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
?>
```

and when called to execute (through a browser during troubleshooting) all I get is:

```
connect_errno > 0){ die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']'); } ?>
```

Printing to the screen.

I've tested the PHP implementation with a simple hello world script which executes fine, so yes PHP is running.

UPDATE:
Noticed that code in my subdirectory /resources/ is not executing at all. Even the simple helloworld.php

my aap.yaml is:

```
application: app-name
version: 1
module: default
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:  
- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /resources
  static_dir: resources
  mime_type: text/html
  application_readable: true

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

Comment: Regarding to your CloudSQL connection issue, I assume you've replaced "project-name" & "cloud-sql" with the corresponding settings for your CloudSQL instance?

Comment: Yes, for sure. Thanks for checking though! PHP in the base directory does execute.

Comment: This is because of your second handler (/resources), which makes App Engine to treat all your files under the resources folder as static files. Separate your php script out to a different folder should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you, this did indeed solve the problem! For some reason I thought that all directories had to be specified if you wanted to be able to use the include function in PHP. Tutorial at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/staticfiles led me to think this, but it does say for STATIC files, which PHP is not.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Mars, static_dir's are for STATIC files only! The PHP handler should cover all directories created in the project.